# (JQuery) Rounded corners in IE?

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, rounded-corners, curvycorners

I already used a lot of plugins such as `curvycorners`, `DD_roundies`, `behavior: url(ie-css3.htc);`, but it doesn't work well, so does anyone know any other tricks I could make for rounded corners for IE? My site is resizable (gum), and color of elements are changing dynamicly, so I can't draw images.

Comment: Which versions of IE are you interested in?

Comment: The best one is still http://jquery.malsup.com/corner/

Answer (score 5):

It's not a jQuery plugin, but CSS3 PIE was made just for this.

http://css3pie.com/

It will work for IE 6 through 9.

Comment: +1 for css3pie, its a pretty nice solution. It doesn't handle opacity in gradients well but rounded corners work fine.

Comment: nice but there is one problem, what would you do if you just need rounded corners n the right side?

Comment: @micha, I've never tried it, but I don't see why it would be a problem.  CSS3 PIE only supports the shorthand property, but that doesn't mean you couldn't specify rounded corners on just one side.  `border-radius:  0px 15px 0px 15px`

Comment: @Brad sure I knew that you can do this with CSS3 but I also know that you can't do that with that .htc file for ie

Answer (score 2):

The overall best way forward is to degrade the experience for IE and not use rounded corners if they don't support it.

if you are dead set on using rounded corners, CSS3 Pie will be your best bet. But the performance of any of these hacks (without using images) aren't not going to create a good user experience. Which, with most all sites, is the most important thing. Especially with your site being resizable. It's going to have to go through and redraw all the rounded corners, which will more then likely break CSS3 Pie in my experience. If you can't use images, I'd look at just doing progressive enhancement / graceful degradation.

Comment: Code examples can be found all over the place. But they would include just using square corners in IE, or using images for corners. You can use a script like modernizer to detect the features of the browser to give you control over the CSS declarations for certain features, or even use a conditional HTML tag to detect IE. Take a look at http://html5boilerplate.com/ for lots of nifty tricks, comments about them and very well documented scripts.